# Dynamics CRM 2011 - How to change the active directory server for an existing CRM instance?

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm evaluating Dynamics CRM 2011.

I would like to point the CRM instance to a different active directory server. Is this possible without a complete re-install?

This is a test CRM instance and only has a couple of active accounts in there right now but it was setup pointing to our corporate AD server and this is proving to be a barrier to testing with multiple different accounts.

Setting up trust from live corporate AD to the test AD is not really an option either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a case to support.

We did a similar change, and they provided us with tools to mass update the SQL table.

Comment: Hi, I have to achieve the same thing - could you direct me to these tools and any docs you found useful?

Comment: I do not have the tools anymore. Support gave them to us.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible out of the box. It has some strict requirements with once it's setup. Things like the org names are pretty much locked in.

Answer (score 0):

If you install CRM on a server in a different AD you should be able to import the database and during the process it will ask you to map existing users in CRM to AD accounts.